# d3 draw once on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im using using d3js to create a list of buttons - which i am able to do successfully.

I am trying to add an X (close) button when you hover over the button. The x appears, however, inspecting the DOM, the x element is drawn endless amounts of times.

```
btnArray.forEach(function (button) {

    const btn = document.createElement('div');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = button.name;
    btn.onClick = evt => {
        // do soemthing on click
    }

    btn.onmouseover = function(e) {
        var me = d3.select(btn);
        me.append('div')
            .classed({'btn-close': true})
            .text('x');
    }

    btn.onmouseout = function(e) {
        var me = d3.select(btn);
        me.selectAll('btn-close')
            .remove();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you're seeing the `"X"` endless times is because the element is being appended at every mouseover but it is not being removed. This is why:

You are setting a class...

```
.classed({'btn-close': true})
```

But you're not selecting by class:

```
me.selectAll('btn-close')
```

It should be:

```
me.selectAll('.btn-close')
//class here--^
```

PS: This is out of the scope of your question, but I'd like to make some considerations about your code. Please take this as a constructive criticism, so you can write a more idiomatic D3:

1. You don't need loops for appending elements in a D3 code. Use *selections*. An idiomatic D3 code has very few loops, if any.
2. Use D3 methods for manipulating the DOM. There is no problem with `document.createElement('div')` (by the way, you're missing the `appendChild`), but you could do that using D3 methods.
3. Instead of removing and appending the same element, you could change its opacity, or the display.